# List Box of Objects and button

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, listbox, mvvm-light

I am new to MVVM . I have list box that populates the list of Employee. I am using MVVM light and Silverlight4

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="Transparent" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         Name="EmployeeListBox" 
         Background="Transparent" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <sdk:Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="Name" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                    Name="EmployeeName" 
                    Height="23" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                    Name="RefresEmployeeName"  
                    Width="20" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Command="{Binding RefreshEmployeeNameCommand}"
                    Content="Refresh" />
                <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" 
                    Name="DeleteEmployee"
                    Width="20" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Content="Delete" 
                    Command="{Binding DeleteEmployeeCommand}" />
                <sdk:Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="Description" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" 
                    Text="Binding Path=Description}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                    Name="RefreshDescription"  
                    Width="20" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Content="Refresh" 
                    Command="RefreshDescriptionCommand" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This displays a list of employees with Name and description displayed in the text boxes and a Refresh button next to Employee Name and Description Text Boxes and a Delete button diaplyed in front of Employee Name Text box.

In my ViewModel I have created 3 `RelayCommands` as

```
RelayCommand RefreshEmployeeNameCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshEmployeeName);
RelayCommand DeleteEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteEmployee);
RelayCommand RefreshDescriptionCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshDescription);
```

When I click on the `RefreshEmployeeName` button the content in the textbox should get reset to its original value if any edits are made to the employee name. 
When I click on the `DeleteEmployee` Button the `SelectedEmployee` should be deleted.
When I click on the `RefreshDescription` button , any edits to the description should be reset.

When I click on the `RefreshEmployeeName` the `RefreshEmployeeName` function is not called in the ViewModel. How to capture the data in the textbox associated with this button. And also how to capture the selected item upon clicking the button. The selected item gets updated when I click near the borders.

Here is my view model :

```
public IServiceAgent ServiceAgent { get; set; }

public EditViewModel(IServiceAgent serviceAgent)
{
    if (!IsDesignTime)
    {
        if (serviceAgent != null)
        {
            ServiceAgent = serviceAgent;
        }

        GetEmployees();
        WireCommands();
    }
}

private void WireCommands()
{
    RefreshEmployeeNameCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshEmployeeName);
    DeleteEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteEmployee);
    RefreshEmployeeDescriptionCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshEmployeeDescription);
}

public RelayCommand RefreshEmployeeNameCommand { get; private set; }

public RelayCommand DeleteEmployeeCommand { get; private set; }

public RelayCommand RefreshEmployeeDescriptionCommand { get; private set; }

private void RefreshEmployeeName()
{
    // have to capture the value within the textbox employee name
}

private void DeleteEmployee()
{
    // have to capture the employee object which should be deleted   
}

private void RefreshEmployeeDescription()
{
    // have to capture the value within the textbox employee description
}

private ObservableCollection<Employee> _Employees;
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
{
    get
    {
        return _Employees
    }
    set
    {
        if _Employees!= value)
        {
            _Employees= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }
}

public Employee _SelectedEmployee;
public DisplayDevice SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_SelectedEmployee!= value)
        {
            _SelectedEmployee= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        }
    }
}

private void GetEmployees()
{
    ServiceAgent.GetEmployees((s, e) => Employees = e.Result);
}
```

Comment: I have posted my VM. Please let me know where am i going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hunch on whats going wrong

The objects within Employees, ( ie each row ) need to be viewmodels with the button relaycommands in them.

You may have the relaycommands on your main viewmodel, but that will never get called because the rows of your listbox are bound to the items in Employees

Comment: Can you please explain a little detail. If you can provide me an example that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a RelayCommand on each of your Employee objects, and bind to that.  That way the RelayCommand execution has all of the object context that it needs to execute.

Add the following to your Employee object:

```
public Employee : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand RefreshDescriptionCommand {get; private set}

    // ... 

    public Employee()
    {
         RefreshDescriptionCommand = new RefreshDescriptionCommand(RefreshDescription);

    //...

    private void RefreshDescription()
    {

         //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Your XAML buttons need to bind to the commands.  Since they're in the ItemsTemplate, they will bind to the RefreshDescriptionCommand on each of the individual Employee objects

```
<Button ...  Command="{Binding RefreshDescriptionCommand}" />
```

When your command executes, it will execute within the context of the object that the button was placed on, so you can refresh your descriptions, update data, whatever you need to do.

You will need to repeat these steps for each of your buttons.

A couple caveats:

1. Make sure your Employee object implements INotifyPropertyChanged (which it will do if you're using MVVM Light, and inherit from ViewModelBase).
2. Don't put this in a ListBox.  That's the wrong kind of control for what you're trying to do.  An ItemsControl is better suited for this.  The only thing the ListBox really gives you here is the ability to select an item, which it doesn't look like you need.  In fact, the item selection behavior will do weird things with scrolling and button pressing at times.
3. This is probably the easiest way to do this in SilverLight.  There are some other options in WPF, with binding to the ancestor, but that's more difficult to do in SilverLight.

Comment: That was a typo error I have Command="{Binding RefreshDescriptionCommand}" in my code. Can you provide an example for your answer choices and that would be great.

Comment: This code is not working :(. Can you please be little more descriptive.... this is urgent please.

Comment: @SnehaSMurthy I fixed the binding statement for the button.  NOte, if this is in a UserControl, you'll have to set your x:Type to UserControl.  Also, I highly recommend against using a ListBox here.  Use an ItemsControl, or a StackPanel wrapped in a ScrollViewer.  You'll get weird behavior if you use a ListBox.

Comment: My requirement is I have a list of Employees and I need to display them on my Usercontrol. I need to have buttons next to each of the property of the Employee and need to update that employee when any button clicked. Please let me know what would be the ideal structure for this. I need to access each property of the employee when anything is changed.

Comment: Aw, darn it.  I just read that you are using SilverLight.  The FindAncestor isn't going to work on SL.  Give me a few and I'll give you a different approach.

Comment: I think, it is not the best approach to place your commands into a model. The commands should be in a ViewModel and bind to LixtBox item using [Binding.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.95).aspx) property.

Comment: I think it is a grey area  to consider whether or not Employee is a Model or a ViewModel in this case, but you make a valid point for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are not being handled because the data context for the buttons by default is the Employee entity. This is because you set the ItemsSource to the Employees property on your ViewModel, then each row is bound to the Employee entity object.  Therefore, the Command bindings are looking for the Command handlers on the Employee object and not the ViewModel.

You need to set the source on the Command to point back to your view model, where the command handlers exist.  Here is an example:

```
Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=RefreshEmployeeNameCommand}"
```

"**ViewModel**" is the name of the EditViewModel instance that was created for the view.